# Injecting object instead of function for Javascript array sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, v8

I'm trying to sort an array of objects in javascipt. Sort order itself depends on two factors: object's properties and a value of a single external variable. I know that I can use array.sort(sortFunction) to inject custom function, but I need to use a different function depending on the external variable (which is fixed during sorting).

I reduced the sorting to minimal test case which shows the problem and trying to inject "descending/ascending" parameter, although the real prolem is much more complex. I know I can reverse() the result, but that's not an issue here.

Here's the code:

```
var ar = [ 10, 3, 5, 17 ];
var ns = new nsort();
ar.sort(ns.sort);
console.log(ar);

function nsort()
{
    this.desc = true;
    this.sort = function(a,b) {
        console.log(this.desc);
        if (this.desc)
            return b-a;
        else
            return a-b;
    }
}
```

and here's the output (using Node.js)

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
[ 3, 5, 10, 17 ]
```

It looks like array sorting code extracts the function outside of parent object while sorting.

Any ideas why is this happening and what would be the proper way to do it?

**Update:** I did find a way to make it work:

```
var ar = [ 10, 3, 5, 17 ];
var ns = new nsort(true);
ar.sort(ns.sort);
console.log(ar);

function nsort(desc)
{
    this.sort = function(a,b) {
        if (desc)
            return b-a;
        else
            return a-b;
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea? Or is there something better?

Comment: Regarding your update, that's a valid solution, but is a little different from the original. It depends on the actual use. If all you want is to create an ascending or descending function, then I wouldn't bother with a constructor. If you intend to store other properties on an object, then you may want one.

Comment: Regarding you "Is there a better way?" question, the answer is it depends.  Your update (and my answer) rely on the being explicit about the context of `this` at the point of sorting at the expense of duplicating references to `ns`.  user1689607 has probably a nicer approach which says that "The sort method inside my `nsort` object will always interpret `this` on the `nsort` object containing the called function."  Don't you love these JavaScript context problems? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ns.sort` is losing its calling context. In other words, once you pass it to `.sort()`, it no longer has any connection to the `ns` object.

You can have the function reference the object directly by making a variable in the constructor point to it, and having the sort function reference the variable.

```
function nsort()
{
    this.desc = true;
    var self = this;
    this.sort = function(a,b) {
        console.log(self.desc);
        if (self.desc)
            return b-a;
        else
            return a-b;
    }
}
```

Or if you're in a modern environment like NodeJS, you can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to permanently affix the calling context value to the function.

```
function nsort()
{
    this.desc = true;
    this.sort = function(a,b) {
        console.log(this.desc);
        if (this.desc)
            return b-a;
        else
            return a-b;
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: +1 for being first and giving a good explanation.  I was going to delete my answer since you _were_ first, but left it in because we are using `bind` in different places.

Comment: I guess instead of var self=this; I could simply use var desc = true; Is there any drawback to that?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov: Not at all. It all depends on your actual use. But if you do that, there doesn't seem to be much use for a constructor function. In fact I would think you'd just create two separate functions and use them when you want to ascend or descend.

Comment: As I wrote, it is not only asc/desc, that's just simplified. In reality the parameter is an integer which is used for some complex if/else rules. So, there are not only 2 functions, but rather 20+ different functions.

Comment: I just met with drawback for var: when I want to change it, I need to write a setter method as it is not available via object.property notation. So I should either use bind() or self or create object with "new" for each parameter.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov: So it seems like you are creating a bunch of similar but unique sorter functions that can be reused for different Arrays. Does this sound right? Or is there a closer relationship between the Arrays and the sorters? Depending on the answer, you may want to take a more functional approach, and create a function factory.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/XSADj/) of using a function factory to create custom sorters where the only difference is the integer you provide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bind`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/fub49/.

```
var ar = [ 10, 3, 5, 17 ];
var ns = new nsort();
ar.sort(ns.sort.bind(ns));
console.log(ar);

function nsort() {
    this.desc = true;
    this.sort = function(a,b) {
        console.log(this.desc);
        if (this.desc)
            return b-a;
        else
            return a-b;
    }
}
```

In a nutshell this says "use the sorting function `ns.sort` but call it so that internally that function uses `ns` for the value of the `this` expression.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of `bind` you could also use this pattern (using a closure):

```
function nsort(desc)
{
   desc = desc || false;
   this.setDesc = function(val){desc = val; return this;}
   this.sort = function(a,b) {
        return desc ? b-a : a-b;
   }
}
var ar = [ 10, 3, 5, 17 ]
   ,ns = new nsort();
ar.sort(ns.sort);
console.log(ar); //=> [ 3, 5, 10, 17 ]
ar.sort(ns.setDesc(true).sort);
console.log(ar); //=> [ 17, 10, 5, 3 ]
```

Just for fun, here's a simplification, more 'functional' and avoiding the calling context problem:

```
function nsort(desc)
{
  return function(a,b){
       return desc ? b-a : a-b;
  };
}
var ar = [ 10, 3, 5, 17 ];
console.log( ar.sort(nsort()) );     //=> [ 3, 5, 10, 17 ]
console.log( ar.sort(nsort(true)) ); //=> [ 17, 10, 5, 3 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I discovered while answering comments for accepted answer. "var" is valid approach, but would require a setter function. I wish I could accept more that one answer sometimes ;)